# Forced to discriminate a union type to then perform the same operation (Visitor Pattern for ASTs)

Tags: typescript, visitor-pattern

I'm in the following situation: I'm implementing the visitor pattern to traverse a really simple language's ASTs.

Here you can find a [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgWwgJwJYGMAyrgoIYA2UAvFAN5QBuhcEAXFAHaIBGKA3FKJAwETxI0WHPgK8oAX3YAobtADKwNIwDm2XMkIlyVGvSgBnJalWc5fRcrUjNYyTLlQAkgBMIjYKgBmqFNoqMeEgMRlZm4Pq8ru6ePijiUrIRUADChAQAogAeYMgQBgaoAPaM-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-oLP8ywMIOjSVMOyA5gECKSGWDDVrW5AvuhFQAPRkVAbIALTUVwAAW0CugcjiGlAYHIHkioECAUAmF4KB5C4TSoohgYAowJGkd4ubMRAAB0gRICQxCkLweAuC4vAVmhpF6VAFFQPJxlSehEimRIqqmTyODYUwuESPhVA1sJun6QZlE0XRwCMfZLHJGxHFccAPF8YwAmcRAwl4KJ6QBosEmmY0hnGfJFlWY0llPAIKAYA8hCodZHgoHZcl4QRLnkJZHlUbRDFMbhrGokFHYhbx-GCVFIlnIIeU2IQ1lZLZOEHI5FVEWQ1WGV59V+dATXsRSwWhR1kXRaiOUXP1BBPFl6zSIZtHUdIYGksAXCaJQKAGBAmLaDm6BwJFHiNjBwDqvm95vRSTmEcJxAym5p0QSN+iPc9wBqlA3p5B4DAwzEd0SNo4Ow8AjZAo0n2wcgwyo4jCLyXIN7yZh2GmXJDD4x4UPTXVgkUqZCNw9DPo0wiGWVI5mOVDJD1PWjmJE8kqlqWJCXLNpxH6dTkOE80rRIB4BjyZ+GQKvROY5nJFYA0lkyXddt0Ijm+ukW57l6XJnOW-pzPAFTAsE24Nu2xUWVu1jUFm1AZamWWc7mU82PjnjTvs24wuQCTNnAOT+mU+x4dyy7NUzQznx22zDus4LHO7QHm4yEAA)

I've only four types of nodes, grouped in a **discriminated union**:

```js
type NumericLiteral = { value: number; type: "NumericLiteral" };
type StringLiteral = { value: string; type: "StringLiteral" };
type Identifier = { name: string; type: "Identifier" };
type CallExpression = {
    name: string;
    arguments: DropbearNode[];
    type: "CallExpression";
};

type DropbearNode =
    | NumericLiteral
    | StringLiteral
    | Identifier
    | CallExpression;
```

I've also the following `keyof`, based on the discriminating `type`:

```js
type KeyOfDropbearNodeTypes = DropbearNode["type"];
// "NumericLiteral" | "StringLiteral" | "Identifier" | "CallExpression"
```

And the following utility which, given a `type`, returns the corresponding **node**:

```js
type TransformDropbearNodeKeyIntoDropbearNode<
    K extends KeyOfDropbearNodeTypes
> = Extract<DropbearNode, { type: K }>;

// Examples:
TransformDropbearNodeKeyIntoDropbearNode<"NumericLiteral">; // is the NumericLiteral node type
TransformDropbearNodeKeyIntoDropbearNode<"CallExpression">; // is the CallExpression node type
```

Thanks to that I've implemented:

- the **Visit** type, which contains some information about the visited node

```js
type Visit<N extends DropbearNode = DropbearNode> = {
    node: N;
    parent: CallExpression | null;
};
```

- the **VisitorFunction** type, which is the type for the custom function that will be called on nodes

```js
type VisitorFunction<N extends DropbearNode> = (visit: Visit<N>) => void;
```

- the **VisitorObject** type, which contains two Visitor functions: the first for when we enter a node, the second for when we leave

```js
type VisitorObject<N extends DropbearNode> = {
    enter: VisitorFunction<N>;
    exit: VisitorFunction<N>;
};
```

- and finally, the **Visitor** type, which is able to contain a VisitorObject for each type of node:

```js
type Visitor = {
    [K in KeyOfDropbearNodeTypes]?: VisitorObject<
        TransformDropbearNodeKeyIntoDropbearNode<K>
    >;
};
```

In this way, I'm able to create the following type of object, where the type of the `node` is automatically inferred according to each VisitorObject implemented:

```js
const visitor: Visitor = {
    CallExpression: {
        enter({ node }): void {
            // <-- the node type is correctly inferred as CallExpression
            if (node.name === "add") {
                // ...
            }
        },
        exit({ node }): void {
            // <-- the node type is correctly inferred as CallExpression
            // ...
        },
    },
    NumericLiteral: {
        enter({ node }): void {}, // <-- the node type is correctly inferred as NumericLiteral
        exit({ node }): void {}, // <-- the node type is correctly inferred as NumericLiteral
    },
};
```

Unfortunately I'm having problems into the `traverseNode` function, which is going to traverse all the AST calling `enter` and `exit` functions when appropriate.
This is what I'd like to write:

```js
const traverseNode = (currentVisit: Visit, visitor: Visitor): void => {
    const { node: currentNode, parent: parentNode } = currentVisit;

    visitor[currentNode.type]?.enter({
        node: currentNode, // <-- error
        parent: parentNode,
    });

    if (currentNode.type === "CallExpression") {
        currentNode.arguments.forEach((node) =>
            traverseNode(
                {
                    node,
                    parent: currentNode,
                },
                visitor
            )
        );
    }

    visitor[currentNode.type]?.exit({
        node: currentNode, // <-- error
        parent: parentNode,
    });
};
```

I know that, if `visitor[currentNode.type]` is defined, the `currentNode` is exactly the type of node needed by that call to the `enter`/`exit` function, but I'm unable to express this in TypeScript.

The problem is that the type of `visitor[currentNode.type]` becomes `VisitorObject<NumericLiteral> | VisitorObject<StringLiteral> | VisitorObject<Identifier> | VisitorObject<CallExpression>` (`undefined` can be removed thanks to the optional chaining), so the type of the node taken by `enter`/`exit`, from the TS point of view, should be able to address all such cases, therefore is inferred as `NumericLiteral & StringLiteral & Identifier & CallExpression`.

But this is impossible: those types form a discriminated union!

I was unable to solve it even using a generic:

```js
const traverseNode = <N extends DropbearNode>(currentVisit: N, visitor: Visitor): void => {
```

I'll show my current solution, that is unnecessarily redundant:

```js
const traverseNode = (currentVisit: Visit, visitor: Visitor): void => {
    const { node: currentNode, parent: parentNode } = currentVisit;

    if (currentNode.type === "Identifier") {
        visitor[currentNode.type]?.enter({
            node: currentNode,
            parent: parentNode,
        });

        visitor[currentNode.type]?.exit({
            node: currentNode,
            parent: parentNode,
        });
    }

    if (currentNode.type === "NumericLiteral") {
        visitor[currentNode.type]?.enter({
            node: currentNode,
            parent: parentNode,
        });

        visitor[currentNode.type]?.exit({
            node: currentNode,
            parent: parentNode,
        });
    }

    if (currentNode.type === "StringLiteral") {
        visitor[currentNode.type]?.enter({
            node: currentNode,
            parent: parentNode,
        });

        visitor[currentNode.type]?.exit({
            node: currentNode,
            parent: parentNode,
        });
    }

    if (currentNode.type === "CallExpression") {
        visitor[currentNode.type]?.enter({
            node: currentNode,
            parent: parentNode,
        });

        currentNode.arguments.forEach((node) =>
            traverseNode(
                {
                    node,
                    parent: currentNode,
                },
                visitor
            )
        );

        visitor[currentNode.type]?.enter({
            node: currentNode,
            parent: parentNode,
        });
    }
};
```

I am forced to discriminate against the type, just to please TypeScript, to then perform the same operation.

So, how could I refactor my code, and my types if needed, to reach my goal?